# How to write Rspec Testing for devise authenticate methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
 def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
```

Above is the method for authenticate and that code is from Model.

I unable to understand how to pass warden_conditions as parameter in this method for testing.

Can you please help me how to pass warden_condition as parameter for Rspec (Unit) Testiong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a class method, and `warden_conditions` seems to be just a hash, so you can use something like this

```
let(:email) { "foo@bar.com" }
let(:warden_conditions) { { login: email } }

it "finds user by email" do
  user = User.create(email: email)
  authenticated = User.find_for_database_authentication(opts)
  expect(authenticated).to eql user 
end

it "finds user by username" do
  user = User.create(username: email)
  authenticated = User.find_for_database_authentication(opts)
  expect(authenticated).to eql user 
end
```